# Magento 2 - Call custom phtml before order grid

Tags: magento2, phtml, order-grid, graph

I want to show `statistics graph` in `custom phtml`.

My question is, how can I call my `custom.phtml` before order grid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add new block in your custom module for your custom phtml

File path should be like: `app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Yourblockname.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;

class Yourblockname extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'custom.phtml';


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context, array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    // Add whatever functions you want to use in your phtml

}
```

Add your block in your module layout file in `referenceContainer` content section `above where your grid block call in xml`

Path of xml should be: `app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\layout\vendor_module_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Yourblockname" name="vendor_module_yourblockname" template="Vendor_Module::custom.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Your custom phtml path should be like this: `app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\templates\custom.phtml`

```
   //do whatever html you want to add
```

For graph I would recommend `Google charts`, I share one of the example, you need to customize it up to your needs. Add this library and example in your phtml javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ["City", "Amount", { role: "style" } ],
            ["abc", "123234", "somecolorcode" ],
            ]);
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0, 1,
                        { calc: "stringify",
                            sourceColumn: 1,
                            type: "string",
                            role: "annotation" },
                        2]);

        var options = {
            title: "Your title",
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
            legend: { position: "none" },
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("amount_barchart_values"));
        chart.draw(view, options);
        }
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though I solve this problem but forgot to answer my own question. You also gave the right approach in the answer. I hope it helps others as well.